# How do I route a domain name to specific page on a different domain name? Both domains are registered on the same account

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, forwarding

My client recently purchased a new domain name and wants it to link to an interior page on the current website. Both domains are registered on the same account. The main site is currently hosted on a Media Temple Grid account and I see no option for "forwarding." There is an option to "Point the domain to another server." Not sure if this is more of a DNS record change or an .htaccess redirect?

- The main website is: fairmountstrings.com
- The new domain name that needs routing is: fairmountstringquartet.org
- The interior page that I'm trying to route to is: fairmountstrings.com/concerts/fairmount-string-quartet/

I selected "Point the domain to another server" which made the DNS for fairmountstringquartet.org the same as the main website. I then tried multiple different redirects in the .htaccess file that's on the root of the server but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This reads as if your are mainly struggling with the options that hosting provider offers. That is nothing we can help with. I suggest you ask the hosting provider ,,,

Comment: Do you want the "new domain" to remain in the browser's address bar? Or should/could the request simply "redirect" to the original URL? If you want to keep the "new domain" visible then you could potentially rewrite the URL internally (since both domains point to the same place). But how you would do that, or whether it is even possible, depends on how these URLs are being routed in your site/application. You also need to include your `.htaccess` file, what you have tried and what happened exactly.